# Python: Remove a word from string using lstrip

Tags: python

I have string like: `st= 'Product=Product Name 25'`
Want to lstrip. output desired:  `out= 'Product Name 25'`

For this i am doing like `out = st.lstrip('Product=')`

Here I am getting as output as `out= 'Name 25'`.This is I don't want.
As it is removing all occurence in my string but need to remove the first occurence.

Desired output should be: **out= 'Product Name 25'**

Comment: That's because [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) accepts a set of characters to remove, not a string pattern to remove.

Comment: You say you want to remove the first occurence. That means the string `Product=` can occur _anywhere_ in the string, not only at the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use split instead:

```
>>> st= 'Product=Product Name 25'
>>> st.split("Product=")[1]
'Product Name 25'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace` instead:

```
st = 'Product=Product Name 25'
print(st.replace('Product=', ''))
>> Product Name 25
```

If it wasn't for the `'='` you could have also take advantage of the `count` argument that `replace` has, for example:

```
st = 'Product Product Name 25'
print(st.replace('Product', '', 1))
>> Product Name 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `out = st.replace('Product=Product','Product')` or `out = st.replace('Product=Product','')`. I tend to find that simple and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're reading key-value pairs from a text file, there's a python module in the standard library for that: [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the `lstrip` function remove the characters in chars.

```
>>> help(str.lstrip)

Help on method_descriptor:

lstrip(...)
    S.lstrip([chars]) -> str

    Return a copy of the string S with leading whitespace removed.
    **If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.**
```

So `st.lstrip('Product=')` removes "P", "r", "o", "d", "u", "c", "t", "=" at the beginning of "Product=Product Name 25". Then, the two words are removed!

I think your string represents a "key=value" pair.
The best way to split it is to use `split()` method:

```
st = "Product=Product Name 25"

key, value = st.split("=")
print("key: " + key)
print("value: " + value)
```

You get:

```
key: Product
value: Product Name 25
```

Only the value:

```
value = st.split("=")[1]
print("value only: " + value)
```

You get:

```
value only: Product Name 25
```

If you want a "left-trim":

```
p = "Product="
value = st[len(p):]
print("trimmed value: " + value)
```

You get:

```
trimmed value: Product Name 25
```